# d3.js: Handling multiple brushes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph, brush

I'm attempting to build a parallel coordinate graph as shown by Mike's example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1341021). [So far so good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxLZi.png), but I'm having some trouble with the brush event handling.

Mike's example uses **v3**, I am using **v4**. The v4 update removed `brush.empty()`, leaving `d3.brushSelection(node)` to fulfill this role.

This is my first time using the library so I don't full understand how to iterate over selections in some scenarios. It seems the API wants `selection.node()` as an argument but my selection is not 1 but a collection of brushes.

**Is there a way to implement this in v4 with simple JS constructs (similar to Mike's)?**

Below is Mike's implementation of a brush event handler in v3

```js
function brush() {
  var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) {
      return !y[p].brush.empty();
    }),
    extents = actives.map(function(p) {
      return y[p].brush.extent();
    });
  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
    return actives.every(function(p, i) {
      return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
    }) ? null : "none";
  });
}
```

And here is the event handler again by anon kind soul of the internet, who implemented [parallel coordinates in v4](http://plnkr.co/edit/RkWBgQ6oi584H3212WrM?p=preview). Bonus (theoretical) points to anyone who can explain how this code is working.

```js
function brush_parallel_chart() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dimensions.length; ++i) {
    if (d3.event.target == y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
      extents[i] = d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert, y[dimensions[i]]);

    }
  }

  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
    return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
      if (extents[i][0] == 0 && extents[i][0] == 0) {
        return true;
      }
      return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
    }) ? null : "none";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by referencing the aforementioned snippet from the v4 example.

My initial approach was to iterate over the brushes, and using attributes from each brush to identify if the current point was contained in it's extent. Conceptually this is correct..

**But instead of referring to the brush, d3.event contained all the information I needed.**

```js
const [upperBound, lowerBound] = d3.event.selection.map(scale.invert, scale);

// Or

const bounds = [scale(d3.event.selection), scale.invert(d3.event.selection)];
```

In other words...

**The data from `d3.event.selection` is a number pair that needs to be applied to the `scale` of the dimension (axis) the brush is contained in.**

Once you have the bounds of the brush, it is simple to figure out whether the point in question is contained in the bounds.

`return val >= lowerBound && val <= upperBound`